# Column "..." in field list is ambiguous despite no column occuring in both tables

Tags: mysql

This is common error and already been asked in StackOverflow.
All the answers seems to be pointing that there exist a column with same name in 2 tables and sql is not able to figure out which table it refers to.
But I It's strange that I am still seeing this error despite no column sharing the same column name.

```sql
Select `branch`,
    `count(at least 1 offer)`,
    `student_per_branch` - `count(at least 1 offer)` as `count(no offer)`,
from (
    select `branch`, count(distinct `studentEmail`) as `count(at least 1 offer)`
    from `offer`
    right join student
    on studentEmail = email
    group by `branch`
) as `withoffer`
    join (
    select `branch`, count (distinct `email`) as `student_per_branch` 
    from `student`
    group by `branch`
) as `totals` using (`branch`);
```

Schema
[image]

The error : `Column 'branch' in field list is ambiguous`

Comment: You should at least tell us *what column name* it's complaining about but I'd guess it's `branch` which is a named column in both of your subselects.

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot that , thanks and updating

Comment: So the original tables are largely irrelevant. You have a subselect you've named `withoffer` which has a column called `branch`. And you have a subselect you've named `totals` which has a column called `branch`. Despite using a natural join on that column they do still exist as two distinct columns and you have to arbitrarily pick one.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever `USING` allows such "ambiguity" - when no table alias specified the column name without alias means combined column with the value taken from left table column. And this column is used once in the output rather than when ON is used. This cannot be a source of shown error.

Comment: The error message means `branch` column name in `withoffer` subquery. If such column is not present in the table then the query works well (after 2 misprints fixed). https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6a9383e75636eaf0eeb54235a238d44e

Comment: @Akina I see there is explain written in the link, Do you want explanation of what I'm doing.
I tried to reproduce the issue and found that it's working in dbfiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=201d21d3eb37758b9a5f4f7c0c34823b
It's still not working in my application though.

Comment: If the same query does not work on the same data structure then something differs. Query `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename;` for all your tables and copypaste them into the fiddle. Enable General Log temporarily, obtain precise SQL text received by MySQL, copypaste it to the fiddle with EXPLAIN added. *I see there is explain written in the link* Explain allows to perform SQL query syntax checking without the query execution.

Comment: Alright, I dint have the same data structure though.
I created a minimal reproduction of the issue. the other columns have no involvement at all.

Comment: I cant do `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename;` and paste it online editor. It throws error If I paste it. eg : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=65e8739cbcd0327fc3a028d49f03f7a3
This is generated by an ORM.
Any pointers you would suggest on how I can debug it.